# how i can explode (split) a gived string for text and separator?

Tags: php, regex

how i can parse a string formed from two block:

1. `{ text }`
2. `text`

I have two regex for both situazion:

1. `\{[^\}]+\}`
2. `*.`

But not understood with combine it in one regex. I have thinked to use or ( `|` ) operator doing so:

```
/(\{[^\}]+\}|.*)/
```

But it don't work. How i can solve it?

In concrete, if i have a string as:

```
"{this is first text} this is second text {this is third text}"
```

using `preg_match_all` i want to have somthing as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {this is first text}
            [1] => this is second text
            [2] => {this is third text}
        )

)
```

But i have as result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {this is first text}
            [1] => this is second text {this is third text}
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Thanks very much for help.

Comment: The surrounding `/` characters are not part of the `regex`, they are delimiters. Keep that in mind when you combine two `regex`es. Another thing: inside a character class only `]` needs to be escaped (also `-` and `^` in some cases but those cases can be avoided). There is no need to escape `}`. Read about [regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) in the documentation of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` with a your first pattern enclosed with a capturing group:

```php
$str = "{this is first text} this is second text {this is third text} {} more text here";
print_r( preg_split('~\s*(?:(\{[^{}}]+})|\{})\s*~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE| PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/#preview). Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => {this is first text}
    [1] => this is second text
    [2] => {this is third text}
    [3] => more text here
)
```

**Details**

- `\s*(?:(\{[^{}}]+})|\{})\s*` - matches the following way:

  - `\s*` - matches 0+ whitespaces (thus, removes them from the result)
  - `(?:(\{[^{}}]+})|\{})` - a non-capturing group matching either of:

    - `(\{[^{}}]+})` - captures into Group 1 (so, this will be returned as part of the resulting array) a `{`, one or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`
    - `|` - or
    - `\{}` - just matches (and thus removes in the end) a `{}` substring
  - `\s*` - matches 0+ whitespaces (thus, removes them from the result)
- `-1` is used as the `$limit` argument to return all items resulting from the `preg_split`
- `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE| PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` make `preg_split` return the captured substrings and omit any empty items.

Comment: Thank very much for ansered. How i can exclude {}  when is empty inside?

Comment: If i do: '~\s*(\{[^{}}]*})\s*~'  it continue to capture {}. Why?

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato You need to match `\{}` but not capture, use `'~\s*(?:(\{[^{}}]+})|\{})\s*~'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$str = "{this is first text} this is second text {} this is third text";
preg_match_all('/\s*(?:{})*\s*({.+?}|[^{}]+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

`'/\s*(?:{})*\s*({.+?}|[^{}]+)/'` means skipping spaces and empty braces and graping pieces in `{}` (with something inside including curly braces too) or everything except symbols `{` and `}`.